# Do while, Handler and runnable -Android

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable, do-while

I can't for the life of me get this do while loop running on a button click even with a runnable and handler. Can anyone please show me where I have made my mistake?

```
{//Class start

    Button roll;
    int numberOfDice;
    int diceCounter;
    EditText diceBox;
    EditText outputBox;
    String diceNum;
    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    private boolean Running;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_roller_screen);
        roll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.roll_Button);
        diceBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberOfDiceBox);
        outputBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.outputBox);

        roll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                myHandler.post(runner);
            }

        });


    }


    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

        int dicecounter = 1;
        Random rand = new Random();

        public void run() {
            do{

                int dice_Value = rand.nextInt((6 - 1) + 1) - 1;
                diceNum = diceBox.getText().toString();
                numberOfDice = Integer.parseInt(diceNum);
                outputBox.setText("Dice"+dicecounter+dice_Value);
                dicecounter++;
                }while(diceCounter <= numberOfDice);    
            myHandler.post(this);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.roller_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out if it's my logic or if I'm using runners and handlers completely wrong.

Comment: Can you tell us what the problem is - are you getting an exception? or does it hang? or is it just not working as expected?  and if so what output are you getting?

Comment: Please ellaborate your question proper and explain us, what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: When I click the button to execute the the handler (which executes my runnable which executes the do while) it just hangs and I get the app has stopped responding message, tested in the emulator and an Asus memopad HD7

Comment: Your while loop compares 'diceCounter' to 'numberOfDice' but you are incrementing a variable called 'dicecounter' so the conditions of the while comparrison don't change and presumably it never finishes.

Comment: "numberOFDice" is equal to the user input from "diceBox" so the loop should run until "diceCounter" is equal to "numberOfDice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly an endless loop problem: `dicecounter` starts at one so if you enter a value less than two into `diceBox` the `do..while` loop will never terminate.  The counter should start at zero and you should validate the number of dice value entered by the user (including checking for number format exception, unless the edit control only allows digits?)

But in any case, why is there a `do..while` loop there anyway?  All it does is **overwrite** the text in `outputBox`, so even if the loop  was fixed all the user will see is the result of the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: I'm still newish at this and thought a do while would accomplish my goal. Are the handler and runnable fine though? would they work using a different way of handling the logic?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to achieve.  Do you want the display to periodically show a new random dice?  or show a new dice on every click?  or something else?  Embellish your question with what you're trying to do.

Comment: the diceBox through numberofDice sets the number of dice to be rolled which is also how many times the loop should run. The loop outputs and random dice number into the output box for each loop.

Comment: I got the output working by switching to a for loop, but the output doesn't stop it runs forever.